# get vertexId graphx

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I am new in spark-graphx and scala.
How I could get the id of a vertex in graphx?

This my code:

```
val sourceVertex=graph.vertices.filter { case (id,(_,_,_,_,_)) => id == 0} // The source vertex
var c=sourceVertex.id
```

I noticed that c is not the id of sourceVertex(c=21 and not 0)

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID you're getting, is not the VertexID but the [id()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#id()) function of RDD

> A unique ID for this RDD (within its SparkContext).

Since you're expecting to find only one vertex, you can do it using `first` like this :

```
val sourceVertex=graph.vertices.filter { case (id,(_,_,_,_,_)) => id == 0}.first
val c=sourceVertex._1
```